# How to dynamically import and reimport a file containing definition of a global variable which may change anytime

Tags: python-2.7, global-variables, reload, volatile, dynamic-import

I need to have actual state of my List, which may change anytime.

mylist.py

```
list = {"key": "value"}
```

For first time import it's state is actual, but list in mylist.py may be changed. I need to reimport it each time function is called.

somecode.py

```
def someFunc():
    from mylist import list
    print list
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're using mylist.py as some kind of data store? This is not really what the module system was designed for. If you give a little more context about what you want to achieve, we may be able to help you solve your actual problem rather than just solving this local problem.

Comment: Ok, I write module for Eventscripts (Counter-Strike Source addon). I need to store mp3 filename associated with steam_id. And i need to have ability to edit this list from php. But database are too slow for actions, that appears instatly.

Comment: If you have a database already up and running, I would be very surprised if you can write a value to file and read it again faster than you could write it to the db and read it again. If you really must use a file, why not just write the filename to a text file in PHP and then read it again in python, without hijacking the module system? `filename = open('filename').read().strip()`?  Or, if you want a dictionary, `list = dict([line.split('\t') for line in open('filename')])`?

Comment: Implicitly, `mylist` is readonly as far as Python code is concerned - any changes to it on the Python side will be lost. This really like a poor-man's database driver.

Comment: Neka: use [flask for caching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/caching/) and any database driver e.g. SQLAlchemy. This will give you instant writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function called `reload(module)`

```
import mylist 

def someFunc():
    mylist = reload(mylist) # this may raise syntaxerrors in wrong moments
    list = mylist.list
    print list
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: This is like an accessor method which dynamically reloads our trusty global variable from file every single time we need to access it. It works, but it's yukky. Also, it makes `mylist` readonly as far as Python code is concerned - any changes to it on the Python side will be lost.